.NET 6 generic host run a specific service
How to run a specific service in generic host?
I have several workers in a .NET 6 generic host project. When the app is started, several workers run together.
xx.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerA>();
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerB>();
    }).Build();

How to run like this :
dotnet run -w workerX


maybe just comment all except the one which u want to run/debug?

You could try add corresponding service depending on the arguments.
var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

// Parse arguments for the "-w" flag
string? workerService = null;
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    if (args[i] == "-w" && i + 1 < args.Length)
    {
        workerService = args[i + 1];
        break;
    }
}

if ("WorkerA".Equals(workerService, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running Service A...");
    hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerA>();
    });
}
else if ("WorkerB".Equals(workerService, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running Service B...");
    hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<WorkerB>();
    });
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please specify a valid service to run with -w (workerA or workerB).");
    return;
}

await hostBuilder.Build().RunAsync();

